# Type is not declared error

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I am getting an error saying 'T' does not name a type. I am confused as to what this means. I thought i declared it in the class saying Virtual T?

```
template <class T>
class ABList : public ABCList<T> {
private:
    T    a [LIST_MAX];
    int  size;

public:
         ABList ();

    virtual bool isEmpty ();
    virtual int  getLength ();
    virtual void insert (int pos, T item);
    virtual T    remove (int pos);
    virtual T    retrieve (int pos);
};
```

.

```
T  ABList::retrieve (int pos) throw (ListException)
{
    if (pos <= 0 || pos >= count)
        throw new ListException();
    return item[pos – 1];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write that as:

```
template<typename T>
T  ABList<T>::retrieve (int pos) throw (ListException)
{
  //...
}
```

because `ABList` a class template.

Note that you've to define the member functions in the same file itself in which you've defined the class template. Defining class template in `.h` file, and member functions in `.cpp` would **not** work in case of templates.

Comment: Ah so just add template<class T>